# Printing contents of a hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable, enumeration

I'm having some trouble printing the contents of a hashtable, it seems to just be printing the reference out.

add to hashtable code:

```
protected Hashtable items = new Hashtable();

public void addItem(String itemId, String category, String title, String imageurl, double price, int quantity) {
  //boolean test = false;
  String price1 = String.valueOf(price);
  String[] item = {itemId, imageurl, title, category, price1, Integer.toString(quantity)};

if (items.containsKey(itemId)) {

  String[] tmpItem = (String[])items.get(itemId);
  int tmpQuant = Integer.parseInt(tmpItem[5]);
  quantity += tmpQuant;
  tmpItem[5] = Integer.toString(quantity);
}
else {

  items.put(itemId, item);
}
}
```

view contents code:

```
public void getContents()
 {
  Enumeration e = items.elements();

  while (e.hasMoreElements())
  {
      System.out.println(e.nextElement());
  }
 }
```

results:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@3736e10e
[Ljava.lang.String;@73f17a73
[Ljava.lang.String;@729e4f7c
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've printed the array objects themselves, not the contents of the arrays.  Try [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString((String[]) e.nextElement()));
```